GNU Octave planar embeddings
How can I do planar embedding of k5 on torus using octave?
I want the vertices and the edges to lie on the surface
I'm able to make torus also make on circle I am unable to proceed further
am = 1.;
rm = 3.;
t = linspace(-pi,pi,16);
p = linspace(0.,2.*pi,16);
[t,p] = meshgrid(p,t);
x = (rm + am.*cos(p)).*cos(t);
y = (rm + am.*cos(p)).*sin(t);
z = am.*sin(p);
hsurf = surf(x,y,z);
axis equal;
set(hsurf, 'FaceColor','interp','FaceAlpha',0.5,'EdgeAlpha',0.25);
hold on
plot3((rm+am.*cos(p)).*cos(t(8)),(rm+am.*cos(p)).*sin(t(8)),am.*sin(p), 'b', 'LineWidth',2);

